# Unable to fathom update count INSERT on billions of rows

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, netezza

I am running a Netezza SQL query that is creating a table from a select statement returning almost 8 billion rows. Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE
    table1 AS
    (
        SELECT
            column1
        FROM
            table2 qt
        WHERE
           qt.column1 = '2016-04-04'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            column1
        FROM
            table3 qt
        WHERE
           qt.column1 = '2016-04-04'
   )
```

The driver is throwing this error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [UNDEFINED]; error code [0];   
    --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
    --- Check the statement (update failed).  
    --- Cause: Unable to fathom update count INSERT 0 7779737732
```

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the SQL query you're running?

Comment: Perhaps the driver / db handles only integers that can be represented with 32 bits or fewer, at least in that context.  You haven't really given us much to go on.

Comment: @azurefrog It was tagged as Netezza. I added the query too, although I don't think its particularly useful in this case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is my guess as well, but I wanted to know if there were any other potential reasons.

Comment: `SQL state [UNDEFINED]` just a sanity check, you are indeed connected and have a working/live connection?

Comment: @JohnBollinger According to ibm, it should support INTEGER and BIGINT types (32 bit and 64 bit, respectively) http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBJG3_2.5.0/com.ibm.gen_busug.doc/c_fgl_odiagntz_026.htm

Comment: @SnakeDoc, that Netazza provides a 64-bit integer data type in no way guarantees that the JDBC driver can handle an update count exceeding the capacity of a 32-bit integer.  In addition, it is unclear whether the error arises inherently because of the large update count, or because of something Spring does with that update count (e.g. writes it to an auxilliary table, maybe into a column of type (32-bit) `Int`).

Comment: Is this really a legitimate CREATE TABLE? If yes, can you place it into a stored procedure?

Comment: @Arkadiy Legitimate in what sense? It functions perfectly if I simply place a limit on the number of rows

Comment: in the sense "did you mean to create a table with billions of rows?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are running into a JDBC driver limitation. If you run a INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE AS SELECT via JDBC and the number of rows INSERTed, UPDATEd or CREATEd exceeds 2147483647, you will receive an error message similar to the following:

```
Unable to fathom update count INSERT 0 5120000160
```

The above error message may be different given whether an INSERT, UPDATE or CREATE as SELECT and given the number of rows actually affected. This is a limitation of JDBC specification itself.

Thanks,
Sanjit